# Tic Tac Toe (decoupling patterns and component based design)

Tags: c#, beginner, tic-tac-toe, unity3d

I'm learning Unity with C# programming and am trying to learn game design. I know the that the best way to learn games programming is to recreate some existing games, and this is my code to create Tic Tac Toe. It's not 100% complete yet but it will be eventually.

However, my question is regarding writing decoupled code. I keep reading about writing loosely coupled code and component based design. I know my code is very messy at this stage but I'd like to learn more about writing decoupled code.

I'm currently reading things like single responsibility principle, dependency inversion etc. using interfaces. All these things would make more sense to me if someone could show me how use those concepts in the following code.

How would an experienced unity programmer re-write this code with component based design and decoupling in mind?

Class **Manager**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Manager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static Manager _instance;//Singleton Mananger
    private Rect[] rects= new Rect[9];//Rect to check mouse position and center pawns
    Slots[] slots= new Slots[9];//Slots represent a slot on Tic Tac Toe Board
    Player player; //Main Player
    private int pawn1match=0;//checks the number of times pawn 1 appears
    private int pawn2match=0;//checks the number of times pawn 2 appears
    private int emptymatch=0;// check if slot is empty
    public GameObject Pawn1 { get; set; }//Pawn 1 gameobject
    public GameObject Pawn2 { get; set; }// Pawn 2 gameobject
    public bool turn;//holds whether turn has been taken or not
    public bool taketurn;//this variable checks if player turn has finished so the slotchecker can run

    List<int> freeSlots = new List<int> (); //List to hold free slots left
    private List<int> winslot=new List<int>();//List to hold winning slots
    private bool aiwinning=false;//if the AI is winning its true
    private bool playerwinning=false;//if Player is winning its true


    public static Manager Instance 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _instance;
        }

    }

    void Awake(){

        if (_instance != null && _instance != this) {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        } else {
            _instance = this;
        }

    }

    void Start () {

        player = GetComponent<Player> ();
        turn = true;
        taketurn = false;
        Pawn1 = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath ("Assets/X.prefab", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
        Pawn2 = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath ("Assets/O.prefab", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;


        for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++) {
            slots [i] = new Slots ();
        }

        slots [0].Rect = new Rect (-3, 1, 2, 2);
        slots [1].Rect = new Rect (-1, 1, 2, 2);
        slots [2].Rect = new Rect (1, 1, 2, 2);
        slots [3].Rect = new Rect (-3,-1, 2, 2);
        slots [4].Rect = new Rect (-1,-1, 2, 2);
        slots [5].Rect = new Rect (1,-1, 2, 2);
        slots [6].Rect = new Rect (-3, -3, 2, 2);
        slots [7].Rect = new Rect (-1, -3, 2, 2);
        slots [8].Rect = new Rect (1, -3, 2, 2);


    }

    void Update(){

        player.takeTurn (slots, Pawn1);
        slotsChecker ();
        aiTurn ();
        slotsChecker ();


    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {

    }

    public void slotsChecker()
    {
        if (turn == false)
        {
            freeSlots.Clear();
            winslot.Clear();
            checkRow(0, 1);
            checkRow(3, 1);
            checkRow(6, 1);
            checkRow(0, 3);
            checkRow(1, 3);
            checkRow(2, 3);
            checkRow(0, 4);
            checkRow(2, 2);

            turn = true;
        }



    }


    void checkRow(int init, int count)
    {
        emptymatch = pawn1match = pawn2match = 0;
        int emptyindex=0;
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            if (slots [init].Used==false) 
            {
                emptymatch += 1;
                emptyindex = init;
                if (freeSlots.Contains(init))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    freeSlots.Add (init);
                }

            }

            else if (slots [init].Pawn.tag==Pawn1.tag) 
                {
                    pawn1match += 1;
                } 

                else if (slots [init].Pawn.tag==Pawn2.tag) 
                    {
                        pawn2match += 1;
                    } 

            if (pawn1match == 3)
                gameOver (Pawn1);
            else if (pawn2match == 3)
                gameOver (Pawn2);


            init += count;

        }

        if (pawn2match == 2 && emptymatch==1) 
        {
            winslot.Add(emptyindex);
            aiwinning = true;
        }
        else
            if (pawn1match == 2 && emptymatch==1) 
            {
                winslot.Add(emptyindex);
                playerwinning = true;
            }

    }

    void aiTurn()
    {
        if (taketurn == true && turn==true) 
        {
            if (aiwinning) 
            {
                slots [winslot[0]].Pawn = Instantiate (Pawn2, slots [winslot[0]].Rect.center, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            }
            else 
            if (playerwinning) 
            {
                slots [winslot[0]].Pawn = Instantiate (Pawn2, slots [winslot[0]].Rect.center, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            } 

            else 
            {
                int i = Random.Range (0, freeSlots.Count - 1);
                slots [freeSlots [i]].Pawn = Instantiate (Pawn2, slots [freeSlots [i]].Rect.center, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            }           

            taketurn = false;
            turn = false;
        }

    }

    void gameOver(GameObject pawn)
    {
        Debug.Log (pawn.name +"Won");

    }


}
```

Class **Player**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void takeTurn(Slots[] slots, GameObject pawn)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0) && slots[i].Rect.Contains (getMousePosition ()) && slots[i].Pawn==null && (Manager.Instance.turn==true)) 
            {
                slots[i].Pawn=Instantiate (pawn, slots[i].Rect.center, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                slots[i].Used = true;
                Manager.Instance.turn = false;
                Manager.Instance.taketurn = true;
            }
        }
    }

    Vector2 getMousePosition()
    {

        Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        return new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos).x,Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos).y);
    }
}
```

Class **Slots**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Slots  {

    // Use this for initialization
    private GameObject pawn;
    private Rect rect;


    public GameObject Pawn { get; set; }
    public Rect Rect { get; set; }
    public bool Used { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's is no use of interfaces in a Tic Tac Toe game. They are used whenever many objects have things in common, this allows you to group them up easily. Imagine a big mmorpg game they have a lot of different mobs and a lot of different interfaces, but probably they all inherit from 1 base interface, which includes the signature of methods and variables such as :

```
public interface IMonster
{
    double Health { get; set; }
    double Mana { get; set; }
    void MoveUnitWithAI();
    bool IsColliding { get; set; }
    // and many others
}
```

Now some will have 100 health others will have 200, but they are all monsters in the end, you can easily put them in an array of `IMonster[]`, but this just by itself does nothing since Interfaces cant be instantiated, what that means is you need to have classes that inherit from this interface and implement it's content. Here's an example I made in paint for you to see how the scheme might look for a monster classes hierarchy :

[image]

Note that you can inherit only 1 class, but you can inherit unlimited amount of interfaces so depending on the complexity of your game the abstract class will inherit multiple interfaces and probably implement most of them. Now knowing this you can probably conclude that there is no real reason to use interfaces in a simple Tic Tac Toe game.

Anyway looking at your code :

1. You are inconsistent where you put modifiers some variables have the `private` modifier others don't.
2. Your variables don't follow any convention at all.

> Private fields should be written in Camel case typing : `private var someVariable`
>
> Any public variables should follow Pascal case typing - `public var SomeVariable { get; set; }`
>
> Any type of method no matter what modifier it has it should follow the Pascal case typing - `public/private/internal/protected void SomeMethod()`

3. In your manager class you are not using `LateUpdate` method it has empty body but it's still there you better remove it.
4. Your classes should have constructors this is a special kind of method which is called whenever a new instance of your class is created it works in similar way to the `Start` and `Awake` functions of Unity. This allows you to initialise your variables right when the class is created, thus reducing the chance of NullReferenceException. Your constructor parameters should contain only the variables you can give at initialisation some variables might be set later on. Here's and example of constructor for your `Slots` class

   public Slots(Rect rect)
   {
        Rect = rect;
   }

Now here you have 2 useless variables `private GameObject pawn` and `private Rect rect;` delete them. You should come up with a better name for `public Rect rect`.

5. You don't seem to know that using `!` in front of an expression will negate it, I'm looking at this snippet

   ```
   if (freeSlots.Contains(init))
   {
   }
   else
   {
       freeSlots.Add (init);
   }
   ```

   You can simply do

   ```
   if (!freeSlots.Contains(init))
   {
       freeSlots.Add (init);
   }
   ```
6. The way you check if there's a winner isn't the best way to go. What I would recommend is first sort your `Slots[]` like this :

   [image]

Now you should work with the indexes of your array here's an example method

```
private void ManualCheck(int slot1, int slot2, int slot3)
    {
         if (Slots[slot1].Pawn.tag == Slots[slot2].Pawn.tag && Slots[slot1].Pawn.tag == Slots[slot3].Pawn.tag)
         {
             Debug.Log (Slots[slot1].Pawn.name +" Won");
         }
    }
```

It might require some fixing I haven't tested this, but I'm pretty sure it should work like this.

And the usage :

```
ManualCheck(0, 1, 2);
ManualCheck(3, 4, 5);
ManualCheck(6, 7, 8);
ManualCheck(0, 3, 6);
ManualCheck(1, 4, 7);
ManualCheck(2, 5, 8);
ManualCheck(0, 4, 8);
ManualCheck(2, 4, 6);
```

However this will only work if there's never a Tie. I see you haven't implemented this one yet so I will help you a little bit. Declare a boolean variable called `haveWinner`. You will change it's value inside the `ManualCheck` method whenever we find a winner. Next you will need some *LINQ* to determine whether the entire board is filled and add few more lines under the place where you check if the board is full

```
using System.Linq;

ManualCheck(0, 1, 2);
ManualCheck(3, 4, 5);
ManualCheck(6, 7, 8);
ManualCheck(0, 3, 6);
ManualCheck(1, 4, 7);
ManualCheck(2, 5, 8);
ManualCheck(0, 4, 8);
ManualCheck(2, 4, 6);
if (haveWinner) 
{
    return;
}
int count = Slots.Count(slot => slot.Used);
if (count != Board.Length) 
{
    return;
}
Debug.Log("Tie");
```

7. Fix your formatting, also `else if` is usually written on 1 line not 2.

If you really want to practice *Interfaces* you should first learn what is inheritance, all the different type of classes, constructors and their modifiers, more in-depth look at how properties work. I learnt those while I was creating a Poker application you can see the code in my profile it's in my questions, also a Chess game would be fun to make and also give you a good idea of how those things work, again I have done this and it's in the questions of my profile.

*HOWEVER, You should read more about unity and how it works because say you are dealing with, for example, **"different varieties of projectile"**. Ok? All you can possibly do in a game engine is have **GameObject**. There is nothing else, whatsoever, in a game engine.*

*There are no "objects", no "inheritance" - there's just nothing, at all, other than **GameObject**. (Which carry the transfor tensors, which integrate to the GPU chip, and the rendering cycle, and hence it's a game engine.)*

*There is absolutely nothing, whatsoever, in Unity other than "GameObject". Note that you cannot in any way, at all, modify, change, vary or indeed do anything - whatsoever - to GameObject. Unity is not even **vaguely** OO or structuring. Unity is as OO as, say, my kitchen table.*

*Don't forget too that game engines have utterly no connection to programming where you have concepts like "classes" that may or may not be "instantiated" and so on. The only thing in a game engine is a whole lot of **GameObjects**.*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Also good to know about the conventions. I will keep that in mind. You've been a great help.